# Проверьте сочинение

Tags: обучение

История развития крылатых насекомых таит в сеье множество тайн. Учёны до сих пор точно не знаю,как и почему насекомые научились летать. 
   Г.Рогов в своём тексте поднимает проблему желания человека полететь так,как летаю птицы,насекомые. 
   Автор восхищается полёту ласточек,стрижей,ловко вальсирующей меж цветками куста шиповника пчелы. Какое же это чудо! Но,затрагивая вопрос о полёте сложно однозначно ответить,что людям не подвластен этот божий дар,как птицам,мотылькам,жукам,стрекозам. 
   Автор утверждает,что на протяжении всего существования человечества людям хотелось взмахнуть руками,как крыльями. Между тем о перемещениях человека в воздушном пространстве без помощи сложных устройств разговоры идут давно,например о левитации - перемещении человека над землёй. Это явление,когда человек воспаряет над землёй и висит в воздухе. Примеру левитации служат ряд иллюзионистов,фокусников.И,глядя на их трюки,мы восхищаемся как же это возможно? Но это лишь попытка произвести на нас впечатление,удивить.Такой ореол загадочности имеет важный смысл,но летать именно как птицы или насекомые,используя свою собственную силу,мечтают бесчисленное множество людей. В своём тексте Рогов упоминае о Леонардо Да Винчи,который один из первых,кто определил своё время,создав талантливые проекты летательных машин. 
   Моё мнение подтверждает и легенда о Дедале и сыне его Икаре.Самодельные крылья из перьев птиц,которые смастерил себе Дедал,и которые стали причиной гибели неосторожного Икара. Этот миф рассказывает о попытке человека подняться в небеса,хоть это и губительно закончилось. Стремление Икара Икара высоко поднятся в небо разрушает всякие стереотипы
   Вспомним пример из пьесы А.Н Островского"Гроза". Порыв главной героини,Катерины. Она сожалела, что не может  воспарить, как птица, и вырваться из «тёмногоцарства», где ей стало невозможно жить 
   В заключении всего вышеисказанного ещё раз подчеркну:человек,мечтая о полёте в небо,должен чётко понимать,что физически это невозможно. Ведь недаром говорят,что рождённый ползать летать не может. 
 СОЧИНЕНИЕ Я ПИСАЛА ПО ТЕКСТУ Г.РОГОВА. ДОПОЛНИТЕ,ЕСЛИ ЭТО НУЖНО,МОЁ СОЧИНЕНИЕ,ВНЕЧИТЕ ИСПРАВЛЕНИЯ,ЕСЛИ НЕ ТРУДНО! ЗАРАНЕЕ СПАСИБО

Comment: Вы для начала хотя бы очевидные опечатки исправьте после Ворда (или чем Вы там проверяли).

Comment: Невозможно оценивать содержание сочинения, не читая исходного текста. Опечатки нужно исправить самой, это очевидно. Прочитайте внимательно и исправьте окончания слов. Далее разделите текст на абзацы. Все эти недостатки затрудняют чтение текста. А потом подойдите к своему учителю. Уверена, он вам не откажет.

Comment: Виктория, примите ответ, нажмите на галочку слева от вопроса. Хоть как-то нужно поблагодарить за хорошее сочинение.

Comment: Так же к проблеме "стремление человека к чему-то новому " может подойти произведение "Омон Ра" Виктора Пелевина.
Или произведения Жюля Верна (как вариант)

Comment: Для начала. Вы уверены, что "так же"? А не "также"?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что проблема сформулирована нечётко. Здесь 2 основных проблемы:

1. Проблема загадок в истории существования живых организмов на Земле.
2. Сможет ли человек научиться летать так, как это делают птицы и насекомые?

Вы соединили в своём рассуждении обе, это минус. Если взять вторую, возможно так:

Сможет ли человек научиться летать так, как это делают птицы и насекомые? Над этим задумывается автор в данном фрагменте.

Решая проблему, автор рассуждает о том, что человек — вершина эволюции или Божьего замысла.Человечество научилось летать на монгольфьерах, самолётах, вертолётах и ракетах, но этого ему мало.Ему,«рождённому ползать», важно летать, как птицы и мотыльки.Г. Рогов приводит в пример попытки Леонардо да Винчи
 бросить вызов и природе, и высшему разуму. Его  блестящие проекты летательных машин, в том числе и вертолёта, и парашюта, опередили время, но были тщетны: без механизма человек не взлетал. Его попытки были повторены в 20 веке - и тоже безуспешно.Однако давно уже идут разговоры о левитации — перемещении человека во времени и пространстве, автор вспоминает танцы мистиков — дервишей, умеющих во время своих кружений взлетать в небо, а затем возвращаться на землю. Автор предполагает: "А может быть, он, человек, не там ищет?" он призывает прислушаться к замечаниям  учёных, которые утверждают, что эволюция крылатых насекомых есть тайна, не имеющая объяснения. Так полетит ли человек?

Позиция автора - позиция мечтателя и в то же время разумного человека, она содержится в его словах :"Думаю, полетим.С одним условием: ежели это будет угодно самим НЕБЕСАМ..."

Я согласна с автором, человек сможет полететь только с позволения Высшего разума. Пока, видимо, этого позволения нет. Пока человек летает только в фантастических произведениях и легендах, таких, как миф о Дедале и сыне его Икаре.Дедал сделал крылья себе и  сыну, чтобы улететь с острова Крит. Рыбаки подумали, что это крылатые боги пролетают над землёй. Икара захватил вольный полёт, он забыл предостережение отца и взлетел к самому солнцу, воск растаял, крылья упали, Икар разбился. Человеку нельзя забывать о своих возможностях, но мечтать о полётах ему никто не запретит. Дедал проклял своё искусство,но люди запомнили этот первый полёт, и с тех пор в их душах жила мечта о покорении воздуха, о просторных небесных дорогах...

Эта же тема преждевременности полётов человека - в романе писателя-фантаста Александра Беляева «Ариэль». В основу романа положен образ человека, способного летать без каких-либо приспособлений.Английскому учёному Чарлзу Хайду удается открыть способ, позволяющий любому живому существу летать, используя броуновское движение  молекул. Юноша Ариэль получил уникальные физические способности, но при этом совершенно не способен к жизни в жестоком капиталистическом мире, что делает его игрушкой в руках людей, стремящихся к наживе. Человеческое общество не готово к таким возможностям.

Порассуждав вместе с автором над проблемой отношения к мечте человека летать, мы приходим к выводу о преждевременности попыток её осуществить, Высший разум сам решит, когда человечеству это будет по силам, когда это будет отвечать требованиям времени.

Comment: Исходный текст здесь: http://egedb.ru/task/3/74

Comment: Вы фактически написали новое сочинение. Надеюсь, автору вопроса это поможет.+!!!

Comment: Судя по новому вопросу - не помогло.

Comment: Даже спасибо не сказали.

Comment: Огромный + Людмиле и от меня